# accessing controller variables in model CakePHP

Tags: cakephp-1.3

I have two variables in my controller in CakePHP which are accessed using

```
$this->data['General']['q']

$this->data['General']['typesearch'].
```

How Do I refer to these variables in the model???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't specify why do you need those variables in your model. Because the context is very important for this kind of questions, it's hard to accurately answer the one without it.

Well, you could try defining variables in your model first:

```
Class MyModel Extends AppModel {
    var $q;
    var $typesearch;
}
```

Then, in your controller you could try to pass the values of controller variables to those variables:

```
$this->MyModel->q = $this->data['General']['q'];
$this->MyModel->typesearch = $this->data['General']['typesearch'];
```

---

Regards, 
Hiawatha

Comment: Thank you very much Hiawatha.Actually I am building a search engine and the q is the searchterm and the searchtype is either web,image or news.