# Access variable in model

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

User will set two parameters `$from` and `$to` which will be then used to make query to fetch related data info.

So i want to access these variables in model instead of repeating them each time in query

**Controller**

```
function index()
{
        $this->CompCalculation->from="2013-07-01";
        $this->CompCalculation->to="2013-07-01";
        pr($this->CompCalculation->find('first'));
}
```

**Model**

```
class CompCalculation extends AppModel {

    var $name = 'CompCalculations';

    var $hasMany = array(
        'Leave' => array(
            'className' => 'Leave',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'conditions' =>  array('from >= ' => $from,
                              'to <= ' => $to
                             ),
        ),
        'Timesheet' => array(
            'className' => 'Timesheet',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'conditions' => array('from >= ' => $from,
                              'to <= ' => $to
                             ),
        ),
        'CompLeave' => array(
            'className' => 'CompLeave',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'conditions' => array('from >= ' => $from,
                              'to <= ' => $to
                             ),
        ),
        'Attendance' => array(
            'className' => 'Attendance',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'conditions' => array('from >= ' => $from,
                              'to <= ' => $to
                             ),
        ),
    );
}
```

**I have already tried following solutions**

[Php Variable in Cakephp Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11840406/php-variable-in-cakephp-model)

[accessing controller variables in model CakePHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10987489/accessing-controller-variables-in-model-cakephp/1098803)

### **Update**

**Controller**

```
function index()
{
    $this->CompCalculation->sett('2010-09-09'); 
}
```

**Model**

```
class CompCalculation extends AppModel {

var $name = 'CompCalculations';
public $from='01-01-01';
    public $from='11-11-11';
public function sett($fr)
{
    echo $this->from;
    echo $this->from=$fr;
    pr($this->find('first'));
    echo $this->from;
}

public function __construct($id = false, $table = null, $ds = null) {
$this->hasMany =array(
    'Leave' => array(
        'className' => 'Leave',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'conditions' =>  array('STR_TO_DATE(Leafe.from,"%W %d %M %Y") >= ' => $this->from,
                          'STR_TO_DATE(Leafe.to,"%W %d %M %Y") <= ' => $this->to
                         ),
    ),
    'Timesheet' => array(
        'className' => 'Timesheet',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'conditions' => array('STR_TO_DATE(from_date,"%b %d,%Y") >= ' => $this->from,
                          'STR_TO_DATE(from_date,"%b %d,%Y") <= ' => $this->to
                         ),
    ),
    'CompLeave' => array(
        'className' => 'CompLeave',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
    ),
    'Attendance' => array(
        'className' => 'Attendance',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
    ),
);
parent::__construct($id, $table, $ds);
    }
}
```

**Result**

01-01-01

2010-09-09

SQL Dump show query using 01-01-01 (Instead of 2010-09-09)

2010-09-09

Comment: the question is why do you want this variable ? You need to first read Cakephp models

Comment: @MoyedAnsari User will select these range in view. So i want all related tables data according to that range

Comment: You should add a function in model which return your desire date with given dates rather than changing models

Comment: Can you please provide me link or example. I am trying this from morning. @MoyedAnsari

Comment: @MoyedAnsari Question updated as suggested. Please have a look again and suggest what's missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a very good practice but you can try something like this in your controller function:

```
$this->CompCalculation->hasMany['Timesheet']['conditions']=
       array('STR_TO_DATE(Timesheet.from_date,"%b %d,%Y") >= ' =>
       '2013-06-01','STR_TO_DATE(Timesheet.from_date,"%b %d,%Y") <= ' =>
       '2013-07-01');

$this->CompCalculation->hasMany['Leave']['conditions']=
       array('STR_TO_DATE(Leave.from,"%W %d %M %Y") >= ' =>
       '2013-06-01','STR_TO_DATE(Leave.to,"%W %d %M %Y") <= ' => '2013-07-01');
```

and so on for others...

By doing this you will be setting the conditions in controller and pass it on to model.  Otherwise you must be getting NULL value in SQL conditions while trying to set the variable in model because you can't set variables like that.

Comment: @MoyedAnsari Have a look at this code. Its working. Did you mean something like this.

Comment: glad it worked for you. again, it's not a very good practice.